KQL - Pass a list from one function to another
I created the below two Kusto functions.
Function 1: GetIds(). The functions returns a list of distinct ids as a column.
Function 2: GetValuesByIds(dynamic: ids)
However, when I run the code I run into an error:
let ids = GetIds();
GetValuesByIds(ids)

GetValuesByIds(): argument #1 must be a scalar expression

I also tried defining a list in-place and tried to call the 2nd function which seems to work.
let ids = dynamic(["1"])
GetValueByIds(ids);

How to use the output of first function as input for my 2nd function ?

You can use the tosacalar() function
For example:
let GetIds() = toscalar(
    MyTable
    | summarize make_set(ID)
);
let ids = GetIds();
GetValuesByIds(ids)


toscalar(GetIds()) returns only the first item in the list.

Below KQL Query is working for me:
let idsList = Get_RIds() 
| summarize ids = make_list(Id); 
Rith_GetValuesByIds(toscalar(idsList))

Output:

Fiddle.
